# How to prohibit null for Java compiler

Tags: java, compilation, null

I wanted to experiment with getting rid of `null` in my Java code and couldn't find anything on how to automatically ensure (in an easy way) that a commit does not contain `null`.

An option may be to run a full syntax analyzer in a pre-commit hook and reject the hook on a positive finding. If someone has a pointer to how to do that it's also appreciated, however, I'd love to be able to tell the compiler to treat an occurrence of the `null` keyword as a compilation error, so that it eventually shows up in a developer's IDE as well as on a CI system.

Has anyone tried this before and/or knows a good way to do that? I know more modern languages like Scala allow compiler plug-ins for that, and I know the APT in Java, but none of that really seems to help in this case.

Comment: This looks like a request for an off-site resource, which is off-topic. I haven't flagged but I recommend an edit.

Comment: Not sure how to edit.. I'm not interested in a resource really.. if I just missed the compiler flag -XYZ that's all I'd need. I didn't want to simply ask "is there such a compiler flag", but if you prefer that I could take a "no" somewhere else for a more appropriate question.

Comment: Well a lot of API methods can return `null` so if you don't allow `null` in your source .. that could be problematic. Until of course a smart guy on your team decides to create `NullUtils` that has a method `isNull`, `giveMyNull`, etc.

Comment: That smart guy isn't on my team.. he works for Oracle and allowed me to write `Optional.ofNullable(thatAPIMethod())`.. so yes, I said I want to experiment with it, but that's because I believe it isn't problematic after all anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting this as a question that asks if it is "theoretically possible" to automate the task of "eliminating nulls" from Java source code.  (Asking for a specific tool that does this is off-topic!)

I'm also assuming that you are talking about static analysis since the checking is to be done prior to commits.

I think that the answer is No.  It is not possible to eliminate all `null`s with static analysis.

Obviously, it would be easy to detect instances of the literal `null` in the source code.  However, other sources of `null` that are harder to detect.

- Class and instance fields of a reference type are default initialized to `null`.
- Arrays of a reference type are default initialized to `null`.
- Many standard classes are defined to return `null` under various circumstances.

A hypothetical static analysis tool *could* detect many cases where `null` will arise because of the above.  But not all.

For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(args[0], "OK");
        String answer = map.get(args[1]);
    }
}
```

A static analyser cannot prove that `answer` will be or won't be `null` ... because it depends on the program's inputs.  It can prove that it *might* be `null` ... but only if it "understands" the semantics of `Map.get` and `Map.put`.

Another:

```
public class Test {
    private String answer;
    
    public Test() {
        if (/* do some complicated computation */) {
             answer = "OK";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = new Test().answer;
    }
}
```

IMO, a static analysis tool that can eliminate all sources of `null` and NPE's in a large Java codebase is beyond the state of the art.  And the Halting Problem tells us that there are going to be certain programs where definitive static analysis is impossible.

Adding lots of annotations (like `@NotNull`) could help the analyser ... provided that it could prove that the annotations were always going to be true assertions.  But you can't just assume they will be, because if you do you have effectively turned static analysis into runtime assertions.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has annotations for it:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

> @NotNull
>
> The @NotNull Annotation is, actually, an explicit contract declaring
>   the following: A method should not return null. A variable (like
>   fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot hold null value. For
>   more information and code examples, refer to online how-to. IntelliJ
>   IDEA warns you if these contracts are violated.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not my point. It's nice, but much weaker than what I'm looking for. It still allows someone to just write a new method and `return null;` from it.